# imbricate two async calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am calling the twitch TV API to get users info from one endpoint and I want also to call another endpoint in the same API to check if those users are streaming live or not, **but only if the first ajax call is successful.** Can anyone give me a hint on how to do it?? My first call below:

```
var getUserInfo = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/?login=ESL_SC2&login=freecodecamp&login=noobs2ninjas",
    // contentType: ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'),
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
        "Client-ID": "5k4g3q59o69v6p9tudn39v50ro1mux",
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("OOPS!!!");
    },
})
```

Comment: Place your second ajax call inside your success handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery ajax function is built using the callback design to deal with its asynchronicity. You have two callbacks, success and error, one of which will fire when you receive a response from the Twitch API. If you want to make another ajax request depending on if your previous request was successful then you can simply write a very similar ajax request inside your success callback function pointing to the new location you are trying to acccess. I would recommend splitting that off into a separate function to maintain the readability of your code however.

Answer (score 0):

The success function only runs if the call was successful.

Trigger the code for the second request from the success function.